# Configuring DHCP for Windows 10 Network Installations

Tags: windows-10, dhcp, pxe, dhcp-server

While following a tutorial for PXE booting a Windows 10 Installation Media, the requirements mention using a DHCP server to do what seems to me to be intercept the DHCP broadcast and instead assign the client an IP from the required DHCP server instead of the default gateway or whatever else is used based on the situation.

I have installed a DHCP server on my computer and followed the directions to segment off part of the network for PXE purposes only.  Given that no conflicts occur like the DHCP server on the router assigning the same IP as the DHCP on my computer, how is the server on my computer supposed to assign IPs instead of the router?

I'm sure I'm messing up the explanation here but this is how I understand it to work with my limited knowledge.  Links to clarifying resources are much appreciated if available.

Answer (score 0):

PXE uses DHCP transactions providing PXE specific parameters to the booting PXE client:

1. The TFTP server IP address
2. The NBP (Network Boot Program)

This PXE requirement require altering the DHCP configuration, this could be a serious matter for some organizations. For that reason the PXE standard included **proxyDHCP**, in this case the task is split in 2 different servers

1. DHCP server: only provides IP and related DHCP options
2. proxyDHCP: only provides PXE related info (see above) only to PXE booting clients.

Then the PXE client perform 1 DORA (Discover-Offer-Request-Acknowledge) DHCP transaction against each server (DHCP and proxyDHCP) in order to obtain all the needed info to boot from a network.
This way you do not need to touch your DHCP configuration nor dealing with potentially overlapping IP pools.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)